# Store updated forms as an array w/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, input

I am currently building an internal tool for viewing and editing SQL-like tables via the web.  I have some PHP and html written that generates these tables and jQuery written that does this, so far:

- Delete Rows
- Add New Rows
- Output form value after entry

The ultimate goal, of course, is to generate a SQL statement using INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc on the modified data.  I have a grasp on how to concatenate the results into such a statement, but could use help targeting columns for it.

My main concern is modifying the form value output function so that I can store any updated entries in an array and output them as a CSV string.  I've read about .each, .map, .push, and .serializeArray.  I'm not sure exactly how to use/combine these methods to accomplish the desired result.  Here are some code snippets:

The current jQuery:

```
$('#add_row').on('click', function(){
    $('<tr><td id="data"><input class ="new_row"></td><td id="data"><input class ="new_row"></td><td id="data" style="text-align:center;"><input class ="new_row"></td><td id = "Delete_Button"><button class="rmv_row">-</button></td></tr>').appendTo('#SQLdata');
});



$("table").on('keyup', 'input', function(){
    $('#output').text($(this).val());
    });

$('table').on('click', '.rmv_row', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
});
```

and the PHP/HTML:

```
<table id="SQLdata">
<tr style="background-color: margin-left:#6b685c;">
<td style="background-color: margin-left:#6b685c; font-family:tahoma,arial,verdana,sans-serif"; colspan="3">

<form style="color:black;" method="post" action="WebEventsStructureColumnTool.php">
        Select your table name:
    <select method="post" name="table_name" id="picker">
<option>Removed For Security</option>
</select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" name="submit">
    </form>
</td>
<td><button id="add_row">Add a Row</button></td>
</tr>

$tableName = $_POST['table_name'];    

$statementObject = $pdo->prepare("SELECT a, b, c FROM tab WHERE _id =?");

$statementObject->bindParam(1, $tableName, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$statementObject->execute();

$statementObject->bindColumn('a', $Col1);
$statementObject->bindColumn('b', $Col2);
$statementObject->bindColumn('c', $Col3);

while ($statementObject->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)){

// Gets an array from the CSVs in the column :     
$Column1 = explode(",", $Col1);
$Column2 = explode(",", $Col2);
$Column3 = explode(",", $Col3);
}
//Fetches the total number of values from each exploded array:
$Count1 = count($Column1);
$Count2 = count($Column2);
$Count3 = count($Column3);
//Establishes the total length/height of the table:

$largest = $Count1;
if ($Count2 > $largest){
    $largest = $Count2;
}
if ($Count3 > $largest){
    $largest = $Count3;
}

echo '
<tr>
<th>a</th>
<th>b</th>
<th style="text-align: center">c</th>
<th>delete row</th>
</tr>';

for($i = 0; $i < $largest; $i++){
        $tableRows[] = 
        "<tr>
            <td id='data'>
                <input type='text' value='" . $Column1[$i] . "'>
            </td>" . 
            "<td id='data'>
                <input type='text' value='" . $Column2[$i] . "'>
            </td>" . 
            "<td id = 'data' style='text-align:center;'>
                <input type='text' value='". $Column3[$i]. "'>
            </td>
            <td id = 'Delete_Button'><button class='rmv_row'>-</button></td>";
}


foreach ($tableRows as $row){   
    echo $row;
}   

echo '</table><div><table><tr id="output" colspan="4"></tr></table>'
```

If anyone also has advice/recommendations on existing code, feel free to criticize.  I am a young developer just starting out and could use all the help I can get.  Thanks!

I added this bit this morning and am now successfully getting CSVs:

```
var string = new Array()
function updateString(){$('#output').text(string);}

$('input').each(function(){
    string.push($(this).val());
});
```

Working on creating three different arrays for each data manipulation option and limiting printing to conditionals.

Comment: suggest you start learning basic dom manipulation and ajax

Comment: just started digging into ajax last week, I was under the impression that it isn't necessary for this part of the project. Can't it all be done client-side until I start actually interacting with our SQL tables? For now, I'm just trying to generate the statement in the browser.

Comment: not exactly sure what you are trying to do to be honest. AJAX seems like a no brainer since php can pull all the field names from any table into array and send them to you in JSON

Comment: Okay, gotcha.  That should help to simplify this process, as I will eventually be using it, anyway.  Presently, I've been going through codeschool slides and tutorials on AJAX.  Do you have any preferred resources for learning it?